Explicit solution to $\int_1^x \lfloor t\rfloor f(t) \, dt$?
(NOTE:
Apologies, but I originally posted this under completely the wrong title...)
Let $f$ be a continuously differentiable function on the reals. I am looking for a way to tackle integrals of the form
$$\int_1^x \lfloor t\rfloor  f(t) \, dt$$
without resorting to summation. (Since $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is discontinuous, I cannot use integration by parts.) I do realise that
$$\int_1^x \lfloor t\rfloor  f(t) \, dt = \sum _{k=1}^{\lfloor x \rfloor - 1} \int_k^{k+1} k f(t) \, dt + \lfloor x\rfloor \int_{\lfloor x\rfloor }^x f(t) \, dt$$
and that the integral $\int_{\lfloor x\rfloor }^x \lfloor x\rfloor f(t) \, dt$ is comparatively easy to calculate for known $x$. However, I am trying using Abel Summation to simplify expressions for summed functions, so integrals such as $\int_1^x \lfloor t\rfloor  f(t) \, dt$ were originally derived from a summation. As a result, if the sum $\sum _{k=1}^{\lfloor x \rfloor - 1} \int_k^{k+1} k f(t) \, dt$ doesn't then resolve into an explicit expression, I am no further forward - and this is often the case.
For example, set
$$f (x) := \text {sinc} (\pi x)$$
What can I learn about $\int_1^n \lfloor t\rfloor  \text{sinc}(\pi  t) \, dt$? The summation approach is unhelpful because although
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\lfloor x \rfloor - 1} \int_k^{k+1} k \text {sinc}(\pi  t) \, dt+\int_{\lfloor x \rfloor }^x k \text {sinc}(\pi  t)
   \, dt  =  \sum _{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{k \left(\text{Si}\left( \pi\left(k+1\right) \right)-\text{Si}\left( \pi k \right)\right)}{\pi } + \frac{k \left(\text{Si}\left(\pi  x \right)-\text{Si} \left(\pi  \lfloor x\rfloor \right)\right)}{\pi }$$
I cannot then simplify the sum.
(Please note that this is just an example; I am seeking approaches that can be more generally applied to $f$.)
For now, I am seeking suggestions for methods to arrive at an explicit formula. If I need to content myself with establishing upper and lower bounds, please say; I will ask about that in a separate question as I suspect it could be complicated!

There's probably no explicit solution, but an upper/lower bound might be possible. I was tempted to play around with Fourier series, but the integer discontinuity could be problematic

Hi @Yves Daoust. Yep, the integral over $[\lfloor x \rfloor,x]$ is pretty easy. I'll modify the equation as written in the OP to reflect this. Thank you.
